# Possible error in the installation of the library Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm new, so sorry for the question.
I have already used the previous post "Alamofire framework not found" to find the solution but I wanted to know if it was my mistake in the installation or depended on something else.
When I create the project, initialize the project with git init,
I add the repository via the terminal Alamofìre (I use the guide on github), when Alamofire.xcodeproj drag the file into your app project navigator of the result 1 time out of 20 is that the library is always alamofire.framework red as if does not exist.
I apologize for my broken English.
I have now solved with the previous post, doing import Alamofire does not give me any error, but it is normal that import.framework appears red and not black as in yours?
Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

If you asks about color of linked libs/frameworks that will be builded (added subproject/as dependency) so YES, for me those libs always red. And this is right - not error because lib/framework will be builded and doesn't exist at this time.

But if you links with builded lib/framework they should be listed in black color.

[image]

These are two examples one below the other two application with alamofire installed.
As you can see in the first in more Alamofire.framework is red while the one below is black.
And execute the same steps, the thing that changes is that we talk about in a universal application with a TabBar and the other is an app only for iphone.
My question was whether Alamofire works in both the app..ti thank you for your kindness